# Mongoose fetch localization multilingual

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, localization

I'm using nodejs with mongoose (mongodb) and I want to filter inside a subdocument array the language selected.

User schema:

```
var localUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
firstName: {
    type: String
},
moreInformation: {
    experience: {
        type: Number
    },
    specializations: [{
        ...
        sports:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'sport'
        }]
    }]
});
```

User data:

```
    [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fc6a379b1d5ff2c42a9a536"
    },
    "moreInformation": {
        "experience" : 2,
        "specializations": [{
            "sports": [{
                "$oid": "5fc6aa91b1db6cd15702241c"
            }, {
                "$oid": "5fcb741e786f0703646befe2"
            }]
        }]
    }
    }]
```

Sport schema:

```
var sportSchema = new Schema({ 
    name: {
       en: {
           type: String
       },
       it: {
           type: String
       }
   },  
   icon: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'file'
   }
});
```

Sport data:

```
[{
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fc6aa91b1db6cd15702241c"
      },
      "name": {
        "en": "Football",
        "it": "Calcio"
      },
      "icon": {
        "$oid": "5fc9598a0955177dee8a3bc4"
      }
    },{
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fcb741e786f0703646befe2"
      },
      "name": {
        "en": "Swimming",
        "it": "Nuoto"
      },
      "icon": {
        "$oid": "5fc9598a0955177dee8a3bc5"
      }
    }
```

I want all users joined with sports by sport id, but filtered by language key like below and replace the sports name languages with the name selected without the language key.

So, if I wanted to select and filter the english language 'en', i would like to get this result:

```
[
{
    "_id": "5fc6a379b1d5ff2c42a9a536",
    "moreInformation": {
        "specializations": [{
            ...
            "sports": [
                {
                    "_id": "5fc6aa91b1db6cd15702241c",
                    "name": "Football",
                    "icon": "5fc9598a0955177dee8a3bc4"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5fcb741e786f0703646befe2",
                    "name": "Swimming",
                    "icon": "5fc9598a0955177dee8a3bc5"
              }]
        }]
        }
    }
}
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) methods like [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) last but not least [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

They define a sequence of steps to help you retrieve your data as you expect

The get the response that you want take a look into the following code and the running example [in here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2vEFAgjRv0N)

*Ps: I suggest you to look into the example in the mongo playground ( link above ) and separate the aggregation pipelines to understand better the proccess*

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    // move specializations array to separated objects
    "$unwind": "$moreInformation.specializations" 
  },
  {
    // move specialization.sports to separated objects
    "$unwind": "$moreInformation.specializations.sports"
  },
  {
    // search into sports collection based on the temporary "sports" attribute
    $lookup: {
      from: "sports",
      localField: "moreInformation.specializations.sports",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "fullSport"
    }
  },
  {
    // as the lookup resolves an array of a single result we move it to be an object
    "$unwind": "$fullSport"
  },
  {
    // here we select only the attributes that we need and the selected language
    "$project": {
      "moreInformation.experience": 1,
      "moreInformation.specializations.sports._id": "$fullSport._id",
      "moreInformation.specializations.sports.icon": "$fullSport.icon",
      "moreInformation.specializations.sports.name": "$fullSport.name.en"
    }
  },
  {
    // then we group it to make the separated objects an array again
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      // we group by the $_id and move it to temporary "sports" attribute
      "sports": {
        $push: "$moreInformation.specializations.sports"
      },
      "moreInformation": {
        $first: "$moreInformation"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "moreInformation.experience": 1,
      // move back the temporary "sports" attribute to its previous path
      "moreInformation.specializations.sports": "$sports"
    }
  }
])
```